# "parseInt from form" and "clearing canvas on start()"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Greeting Everyone,
I already asked for some help with this assignment but the help I got was rather fruitless..
hope this time some1 would be to assist me :( ..

I have to draw on an id'd canvas everytime i  click on a button, 
however after some modification I get the result on my screen but I lost some functionalties,
parsing integer wont work since I get an error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: pGame is not defined
```

Although it is identified and it used to work at an early stage.

another issue is clearing the canvas everytime I click start:

```
function start()
{
 //tried making a counter, if its the first time to click
 //start then do nothing else restore
 // context.restore();

 if (shouldClear==0) {


 setInterval(rotateShape, 30);
 var degrees = 0.0;

  shouldClear = 1;
 }
 else{
  rotateShape();
  shouldClear-1;
 }
 }
```

For reference pursposes here is my full code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head><title>Rectangles</title></head>
 <body>
 <script>

  var i = 0;
  var rectArrayStartX,rectArrayStartY,rectArrayDimY,   rectArrayDimX;

  var RotatingRectangle = function(x, y, width, height, rot, r,g,b){
    var rotation = rot;
    var rotationState = 0;
    this.draw = function(ctx){
      rotationState += rotation;

      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(x+(width/2), y+(height/2));
      ctx.rotate(rotationState);
      var randomRed = Math.floor( Math.random() * 256 );
      var randomGreen = Math.floor( Math.random() * 256 );
      var randomBlue = Math.floor( Math.random() * 256 );
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + randomRed + ", " + randomGreen + ", " + randomBlue +")";
      ctx.fillRect(0-(width/2), 0-(height/2), width, height);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  } 

  var shouldClear = 0;
  function start()
   {
      //tried making a counter, if its the first time to click
      //start then do nothing else restore
     // context.restore();

      if (shouldClear==0) {


       setInterval(rotateShape, 30);
       var degrees = 0.0;

        shouldClear = 1;
      }
      else{
       rotateShape();
       shouldClear-1;
     }
     }

    function construct()
     {
      var count = 25;
       var count = parseInt(pGame.box.value);

      var allShapes = [];
      for (i=0; i < count; ++i) {
      var rotation = Math.random()*.10
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 640);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
      var randomRed = Math.floor( Math.random() * 256 );
      var randomGreen = Math.floor( Math.random() * 256 );
       var randomBlue = Math.floor( Math.random() * 256 );
      var rect = new RotatingRectangle(x, y, 50, 50, rotation, "rgb(" + randomRed + ", " + randomGreen + ", " + randomBlue +")");
      allShapes.push(rect); 
    }
    return allShapes;
     }

    var allShapes = construct();

   function rotateShape()
    {
     var canvas = document.getElementById('gameId');

      if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
      for (i=0; i < allShapes.length; ++i) {
        allShapes[i].draw(ctx);
      }
      if (shouldClear==1) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
      for (i=0; i < allShapes.length; ++i) {
        allShapes[i].draw(ctx);
      }
    }

    }
    }


       </script>
     <div id="rectangles" STYLE = "background-color: #fff68f; width: 600px; height: 420px; 
           border-style: outset;position: absolute;">
       <form name="pGame">
       <center>
         <b>Canvas Application</b><br>
        <input type= "button" value= "Start" onclick= "start()" />
         <input id="box" type="text" size="2" value="10" style="border-style:inset;
             color:red; background-color: black" />
         </center>
         </form>

        <canvas id="gameId" width="598" height="300" 
        STYLE = "border:1px solid; background-color: #fff68f; position: absolute;">
       </canvas>

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Where is `pGame` is defined?

Comment: in the form at the end of my code:                                div ....
        <form name="pGame">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form `pGame` hasn't been created when you try to access it.
Place your script under the form so that the form will be created before the script is executed or call your script when the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event triggers.

Comment: Do you happen to know how can I clear my canvas and start the construction of my boxes and drawing them all over again using my start() function ? that part is also bugging me :(

Comment: @AmerAlmutawa what is the problem you're having? Maybe you should ask another question describing your problem.

Comment: Every time I use my start() function I want to be able to clear my canvas and re construct() my rectangles.. but that doesnt seem to be working, clear worked but it redraws the previous set or rectangles I created. I guess Ill ask another ques. as you advised.